# Rails remote call, response reloads page and jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `destroy` method where:

- It is called via `link_to` and `remote: true`
- After deletion, I want to tell browser to redirect to a page
- And jump the user down to a specific anchor **(this bit isn't working)**

Code looks like:

```
def destroy
  # code to delete objects
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render js: %(window.location.href = "/docs/#{@doc.id}") }
  end
end
```

This works: directing browser to documents page (e.g. `/docs/42`).

But I really want to direct user to documents page **and** jump down to anchor on the page.

I started with the approach below (i.e. create something like `/docs/42#section_2`) but this doesn't reload page.

```
def destroy
  # code to delete objects
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render js: %(window.location.href = "/docs/#{@doc.id}#section_#{@doc.section.id}") }
  end
end
```

Using Chrome dev tools, the javascript seems to be coming to browser okay. Have also tried variously with:

- `window.location`
- `window.location.replace`

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: additional info (apologies for not including earlier) to clarify.

Say we are on page `/docs/42`:

- The `destroy` method is triggered from a button in Bootstrap modal
- Clicking on button should send `remote` ajax call to invoke `destroy`
- `destroy` executes
- Javascript is returned to browser, causing redirect to URL (complete page refresh) to `/docs/42` now with refreshed content
- End goal is to redirect to `/docs/42#section42` (jump down page to anchor)

So what's observed so far:

- URL of form `/docs/42` yields correct behavior
- URL of form `/docs/42#section_21` yields unintended behavior

Unintended behavior observed:

- Page does not refresh (so unrefreshed content remains)
- Underneath modal, I can see page jump to anchor (`#section_21`)
- Modal stays on page

Comment: When you hit the url /docs/42#section_2 at that time if an element contains id with section_2 then the browser will automatically scroll to that element. SO make sure that the same ID is present in the DOM

Comment: I faced a similar prob and `render :js => "window.location = '#{something_url}'"` helped me

Comment: Yup, anchor is valid and present. Have tried with ``window.location`` and ``window.location.href``. Both work when dealing with form ``/docs/42`` (omitting any anchor hash) but fail when dealing with form ``/docs/42#section_21`` with anchor. I added additional clarification info about that I missed out initially.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. It works for me. Did you check ajax response to see the correct javascript code is returned. Something like window.location.href = "/docs/5#section_3"; . If the URL has the correct section Id and the page has a section with that id (section_1) this should be working.

Comment: Thanks. Yup, checked ajax response and expected javascript returned. I added additional clarification info that I missed out initially.